# Oracle Query/SQL tuning

Tags: sql, performance, database-tuning, sql-tuning, query-tuning

I have a table with total 198695 records and 96579 records with project_id =555.
I have list interval partitioned the table by project_id.
If i run the below query(without distinct),it takes 0.75 secs to run.

```
SELECT  KW,SEARCH_VOLUME,TARGET_URL,KEYWORD_TYPE,RANK_DATE,RANK,URL,DOMAIN
from alps_project_theme_kw_v where  min_rank =1 and project_id = 555;
```

while if i add distinct and run the below query, it takes 15 secs to run

```
SELECT distinct KW,SEARCH_VOLUME,TARGET_URL,KEYWORD_TYPE,RANK_DATE,RANK,URL,DOMAIN
from alps_project_theme_kw_v where  min_rank =1 and project_id = 555;
```

For now the results fetched by both distinct and non distinct query is same (1636 rows)
Can anyone please suggest how should i further tune the query?
Please note:- i have only partitioned the table on project_id as mentioned above and analyzed it ,have not created any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding index on project_id will greatly reduce the execution time. If you dont want to add index to the base table, copy the o/p to a temp table, create index on the temp table and then fire the distinct query, I bet will be faster than 15 sec.

Comment: Index on project_id won't help i think cause i have already partitioned the same, so using the partition will be more effective right?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use hints from oracle, 

    for e.g. SELECT /*+ INDEX(INDX1,IDX2) */ * FROM v;

    for fast retrieval of data use  

    SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(100) */ * FROM v;


    try to use combination of column which are in same index 

Refer : 

    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm
```

Comment: are u suggesting creating an index on project_id and using hint on the same?? i have partitioned the table by project_id

Comment: Yes. but project_id would be already indexed if its a primary key. creating index on large data table is not suggested as it takes too much of a time.

Comment: creating index in project_id and using hint didn't help. Any other suggestion??

Comment: Indexed columns are faster because data is stored in indexed order hence faster to retrieve. when using multiple tables, rather than DISTINCT use exists by modifying your query if possible.